# Delphi Multi-Threading Message Loop

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi

My application has several threads:
1) Main Thread
2) 2 Sub-Main Threads (each with Message Loop, as shown below), used by TFQM
3) n Worker Threads (simple loop, containing Sleep())

My problem is, when I close my application, the Worker Threads manage to exit properly, but 1 of the 2 Sub-Main Threads hangs (never exits) when I issue WM_QUIT to close them.

---

```
procedure ThreadProcFQM(P: Integer); stdcall;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
 _FQM: TFQM;
begin
  _FQM := Ptr(P);
  try
    _FQM.fHandle := AllocateHwnd(_FQM.WndProc);

    while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do
    begin
      TranslateMessage(Msg);
      DispatchMessage(Msg);
    end;

  finally
    DeallocateHWnd(_FQM.fHandle);
    SetEvent(_FQM.hTerminated);
  end;
end;
```

---

```
procedure TFQM.Stop;
begin
  PostMessage(fHandle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

  WaitForSingleObject(hTerminated, INFINITE);
  if hThread <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    hThread := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 11):

If I may point to few problems in your code ...

1) You're not checking output of AllocateHwnd. Yes, most probably it will never fail, but still ...

2) AllocateHwnd belogs OUT of try..finally! If it fails, DeallocateHwnd should not be called.

3) AllocateHwnd is not threadsafe. If you call it from multiple threads at the same time, you can run into poblems. [Read more.](http://17slon.com/blogs/gabr/2007/06/allocatehwnd-is-not-thread-safe.html)

As Davy said, use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects instead of creating hidden message window. Then use PostThreadMessage to send messages to thread.

If I may put a plug for a totally free product here - use my [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/) instead. Much simpler than messing directly with Windows messaging.

Comment: D2007+, actually. Time to upgrade, then :)

Comment: Gabr, your threading library looks fantastic - thanks for pointing it out.  Oh, and I'd say your site is "spartan", not ugly.

Answer (score 9):

I've had the same problem, and I found out I **shouldn't** create a hidden window just to recieve messages. Threads already have a message system.

I think that you're creating your windows handle and store it in fHandle, but GetMessage checks your thread's message loop. Therefore the message PostMessage(fHandle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0); is never recieved by the getmesssage.

You can post messages to your thread using PostThreadMessage, and in the thread you use GetMessage(CurrentMessage, 0, 0, 0). The only important difference is that you have to start the message loop from your thread by calling

```
PeekMessage(CurrentMessage, 0, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);
```

You should start with this, than do your setup and than start your loop.

The reason why you should start with the peek message is to make sure messages which are sent during the initialization of your threadprocedure are not lost.

The weird thing is, at the moment I can't find the reference where I learned this, but my guess is the newsgroup community.

Comment: Ooops, sorry my first time here. Didn't know about comments.... I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Davy is right: PeekMessage should be used to create the Message Queue

Comment: You read it on the [MSDN page for `PostThreadMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946(VS.85).aspx). They even recommend having the main thread wait on an event which the thread sets once it's message has been created.

Answer (score 8):

1) You don't need in AllocateHwnd within your thread. First call to GetMessage will create a separate message queue for this thread. But in order to send message to the thread you should use PostThreadMessage function.

Be aware that at the moment of calling PostThreadMessage the queue still could not be created. I usually use construction:

```
while not PostThreadMessage(ThreadID, idStartMessage, 0, 0) do
  Sleep(1);
```

to ensure that message queue created.

2) For terminating thread loop I define my own message:

```
  idExitMessage = WM_USER + 777; // you are free to use your own constant here
```

3) There is no need for separate event, because you can pass thread handle to
WaitForSingleObject function. So, your code could look like:

```
  PostThreadMessage(ThreadID, idExitMessage, 0, 0);
  WaitForSingleObject(ThreadHandle, INFINITE);
```

Take into consideration that ThreadID and ThreadHandle are different values.

4) So, your ThreadProc will look like:

```
procedure ThreadProcFQM; stdcall;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) 
    and (Msg.Message <> idExitMessage) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: As pointed out below, you should create the Message Queue with PeekMessage:

  // Force Message Queue Creation
  PeekMessage(Msg, 0, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);