# Does a Message-Only Window consume fewer resources?

Tags: windows, delphi

I'm creating a window with CreateWindowEx for the sole purpose of receiving messages. Currently the hWndParent parameter is 0:

```
Result := CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, WindowClassName, '', WS_POPUP,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HInstance, nil);
```

I've read that a message-only window can be created by changing this parameter to `HWND_MESSAGE`.

Are there benefits in terms of performance and consumption of resources when using this option?

Comment: You can use built-in `AllocateHWnd` function. Why do you want to do *this* by yourself. It's the bad place for optimization, I'd say. You're gonna make it once (for a common message receiver I hope).

Comment: @TLama: Thanks for the response. The reason is outlined here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322329/how-to-pass-message-to-tapartmentthread-instance-without-creating-windows-handle)

Comment: I doubt it makes much difference

Comment: Fewer resources than what? Than a TForm, or than using HWND_MESSAGE? Than  TForm, absolutely yes, it will use fewer resources. Than HWND_MESSAGE who knows, and either way the difference would be absolutely tiny.

Comment: @TLama: although `AllocateHWnd()` is useful at times, it is also not thread-safe, and does not create a message-only window using `HWND_MESSAGE`.

Comment: @DavidM: "*Fewer resources than what?*" - then a non-`HWND_MESSAGE` window.

Comment: @Remy, the OP explained that by linking the other question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Appreciate the response. Opinion appears to be that any difference would be negligible. Would you mind promoting your comment to an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer definitively. One would imagine that a message only window would be less heavy on resources than a hidden window. But who's to say that it's not the other way around? And perhaps the answer differs with OS version. You can only tell for sure by profiling.

However, you tend not to have large numbers of message only windows in a process. And so even if there's a difference, will it ever be significant? Not likely.

More important differences are to be found in behaviour. The big one is that message only windows don't receive broadcast messages.

Comment: Thanks for this and your contribution to thread safe AllocateHWnd.